# how to make @Html.CheckBoxFor invisible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

how do you make  `@Html.CheckBoxFor` invisible with use of the htmlAttributes?

I tried:

```
   @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.DeleteEnabled, new {visible= @modelItem.Visible})
```

Comment: hey there, can i ask you why you don't just use the Html.HiddenFor() helper instead?? to me it sounds like bad design to have a 'type' like a checkbox hidden, with no obvious explanation. i 'get' the requirement to have it disabled, but hidden is just weird :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.DeleteEnabled, 
                  new { style = modelItem.Visible ? 
                                    string.empty : 
                                    "display:none"})
```

or if you do not need it at the page source at all, nor even hidden then use `@if` for example:

```
@if(modelItem.Visible)
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(modelItem => modelItem.DeleteEnabled)
}
```